# Is it possible to move all the `create-react-app` package scripts up a level?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, webpack, create-react-app

Is it possible to move all the `create-react-app` package scripts up a level?

I have:

```
/server
/client
```

Client is the `create-react-app` app.
Server is an `ExpressJS` app.

They have some of the same dependencies (Lodash, etc).

Right now, both `/client` and `/server` have their own `package.json` and `node_modules`.

On top of that, the root dir has a `package.json` for global dev-dependencies (It's a Truffle / solidity project).

I've collapsed all these `node_modules` and `package.json` files into one package.json and one `node_modules`, sitting on the root dir.

The project is at: `/Users/me/Code/MyProject`
And the one `package.json` is at `/Users/me/Code/MyProject/package.json`
Client (CRA project) is at `/Users/me/Code/MyProject/client`
ExpressJS app is at `/Users/me/Code/MyProject/server`

But, when running this
`npm run start`

which runs this..

```
//package.json
start": "react-scripts start
```

Getting a

```
Could not find a required file.
  Name: index.html
  Searched in: /Users/me/Code/MyProject/public
```

Is there a way to config CRA to have a specific root.
Instead of `/Users/me/Code/MyProject/public`, use `/Users/me/Code/MyProject/client/public`. While, the `package.json` lives in a dir above?

Thanks!

Comment: You could try this solution: [How do I connect a react frontend and express backend?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47612816/8672103)

Comment: I may just not be very well informed, but I haven't heard of using a package.json to encompass both a client and a server - it seems a little odd. But I don't know anything about truffle / solidity either, except that I see that they have something to do with testing. Can this not be installed as dev-dependencies inside both client/ and server/ instead?