# Problem in connecting node js with react js

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I am working on my first full stack application and making a facebook clone till now i made a login and registration system and connected it to express and mongodb as my database, the front end for my login system is written in HTML and CSS only after this i started to work on the main page of facebook in react and made a similar ui in react now the problem is I don't have any idea of how to route it with my express where all the other routes are i mean like i have a login root , a forgot password root and so on i don't know how to show the Facebook front page when someone logs in . So please help me with this.

Comment: I think you should take a look to same tutorial on how to build a web application using the MERN stack.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I connect a react frontend and express backend?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47612816/how-do-i-connect-a-react-frontend-and-express-backend)

Answer (score 0):

So you want to send the login/registration data to the backend? You can use axios (https://github.com/axios/axios). When making an API call, React will try first try and look it up in the frontend, if it cannot find anything it will pass it on. To enable the pass on you have to add this to you package.json.

```
  "proxy": "http://localhost:5000",
```

Of course the 5000 is your port where the express backend is running.

Comment: no no the login/registration part is perfect and is already connected with express the main problem is the facebook main page which is written in react so i want that when someone successfully logs in he/she should be send to that react page

Comment: You can use history form react-router-dom. Such as import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom'; With that you can just push the front page link with history.push('/frontpage') if the auth was successful.